mdspan operator [] doesn't compile in visual studio
https://godbolt.org/z/f4dc83fr3
std::vector v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
auto ms2 = std::mdspan(v.data(), 2, 6);
ms2[0, 0] = 3;


error C2676: binary '[': 'std::mdspan<_Ty,std::extents<_IndexType,18446744073709551615,18446744073709551615>,std::layout_right,std::default_accessor<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator


MSVC doesn't yet support the multidimensional subscript operator. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170:




C++23 Core language features
Supported




P2128R6 Multidimensional subscript operator
no




Workaround: use ms2[std::array{0, 0}] instead of ms2[0, 0].
